# Why YouCompleteMe does not work after dot?

Tags: c++, vim, clang, youcompleteme, clang-cl

I have installed **YouCompleteMe** according to the installation guide. I'm using **gVim** on **Windows** machine. Basic symbolic completion is working but I cannot make it to autocomplete from my headers.

If I have:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> myVector;
```

then it will be no completion found for `myVector.<smth like push_back etc...>`

Vim status bar says:

```
--User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found
```

or

```
--Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

---

### Diagnostics

I started to diagnose the problem. `:YcmDiags` command gives a list of errors coming from header files. As **YouCompleteMe** uses **clang** to constantly compile sources I tried to compile my file with clang. I also know that I should specify command line options for clang in flags in **.ycm_extra_conf.py**. I don't know whether YCM runs **clang.exe** or **clang-cl.exe** but I actually successfully compiled my .cpp file using **clang-cl.exe** manually after running **vsvars32.bat** from command line. I didn't succeeded to compile using **clang.exe**.

Here is my **.ycm_extra_conf.py** file flags section:

```
flags = [ 
'-std=c++11',
'-x', 'c++',
'-I', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include',
'-I', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.10150.0/ucrt',
'-I', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/atlmfc/include',
'-I', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/NETFXSDK/4.6/include/um',
'-I', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/um',
'-I', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/shared',
'-I', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/winrt',
'/link', '/LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x86" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86"',
'/EHsc']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**micbou** gave me an [answer](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1932#issuecomment-174192596) to this question.

> On Windows, Clang uses `i686-pc-windows-gnu` on 32-bit and `x86_64-w64-windows-gnu` on 64-bit as its default target. You need to change it to MSVC by adding the following flag:
>
> `flags = [ '--target=<arch>-pc-windows-msvc<xx.yy.zzzzz>' ]`
> where  is `i686` on 32-bit, `x86_64` on 64-bit and `<xx.yy.zzzzz>` is the version of MSVC. You can found it by running the VC++ compiler `cl.exe`. In your case, since you are using MSVC 14 on 32-bit, the target should be `i686-pc-windows-msvc19.00.23506`.
>
> With the include flags you already added, you should get completions from the headers.

In my particular case `--target=x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.00.23026` flag resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This does not relate to YCM, just answering the plain vanilla approach.

What I usually do, on linux, is extend the `path` to include std library headers like:

```
set path+=/usr/include/**
```

then, we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>.